# How to scale or sculpt on part of a rigged mesh without having to manually adjust rig after?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, scale

So I want to scale the head of a pre-rigged model I bought, but when I do, all the facial bones (which there are a lot of), are now slightly out of place. Is there a way to have them scale with the head? Or maybe a way to scale the head bones of the armature, but not in edit mode so that the head mesh scales with it? I just want to avoid manually moving all the facial bones back into place if that is even possible, any tips? Thanks[image]

Comment: I'm not expert on rigging so I am open to correction and interested in future answers as well, but as far as I know; the mesh and bones are directly linked, by changing one you change the other. As such, I reckon your best bet is unparenting your rig, scale the head appropriately, and then re-parent the rig, using the same weights. Alternatively, you can scale bones in pose mode which will scale the related parts of the mesh, but then you'd have to make sure that the scale is always set with a keyframe for each animation

Comment: Don't scale the mesh.  Instead, scale the bones, like the head bone.  If you need a different center of scaling, make a new bone.

Comment: Not as far as I know.  The best you can do is scale the head and notice the scaling factor, then select the relevant bones and scale them by the same amount.  Then you might still have some adjustments to make.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for the help guys, I will try these methods. I just realized something though. Scaling the mesh won't affect the weight painting right? So technically even though the bones aren't in the "right" place, they will still work properly as they did before right? Because the bones are still connected to the same vertices?

Comment: @Blith Yes, that's correct.  The weights don't change.  But generally, the weights that you want for rotation are a function of the position of the bone, relative to the position of the mesh.  When you move the vertex, you usually want different weights.  (For bones that only ever translate, it doesn't matter so much.)

Comment: @Nathan Ah, ok. Thank you! I will try scaling the bones then!